# Importing python file causes an error, works perfectly by itself

Tags: python

I have two .py files:

dice-rolls.py

```
import random

Dicerolls = open("Dice_rolls.txt","w")

Choose_dice = True

while (Choose_dice == True):
    roll_type = int(input("Would you like to roll a d4, d6, d8, d10 d12, or d20? - type the number \n"))

    if (roll_type < 0 or roll_type > 20):
                print ("Invalid")

    if (roll_type == 4 or roll_type == 6 or roll_type == 8 or roll_type == 10 or  roll_type == 12 or roll_type == 20):
        Choose_dice = False



if (Choose_dice == False):
    min = 1
    max = roll_type

roll_again = int(input("How many times would you like to roll?" + "\n"))

while (roll_again > 0):
    print ("\n Rolling the dices...")
    print ("The value is")
    roll = (random.randint(min, max))
    print (roll)
    roll_again = (roll_again -1)
    Dicerolls.write (str(roll) + "\n")
    continue
```

and variance.py

```
Dicerolls = open("Dice_rolls.txt","r")
Sorted = open("Sorted_rolls.txt", "w")
Mean = open("Calculated_Mean.txt","w")
Varience = open("Calculated_Varience","w")

#sort dice rolls
results = Dicerolls.readlines()
results = [int(i) for i in results]
results.sort()
#Dicerolls.close()


# calculate mean
mean = sum(results) / len(results)

# calculate variance using a list comprehension
var_res = sum((xi - mean) ** 2 for xi in results) / len(results)

#print sorted, mean, and varience
print("Sorted rolls = ", results, "\n")
print ("Mean = ", mean, "\n")
print ("Varience = ", var_res, "\n")


Sorted.write(str(results))
Mean.write(str(mean))
Varience.write(str(var_res))
Dicerolls.close()
```

When run seperately, dice_rolls prints the set amount of rolls into a text document, and then when variance is run it successfully reads the file, and creates more documents with the correct results.

However, if I create a Dice_Program.py I get errors. Dice_Program.py contains

```
    import dice_roll
print("\n Dice Rolled")
print("________________________________________________")

import variance
print ("Scored calculated")
```

The error I get is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dice_Program.py", line 5, in <module>
    import variance
  File "/home/edward/Documents/Python Projects/Dice Roller/variance.py", line 14, in <module>
    mean = sum(results) / len(results)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

When running some print tests, the files work perfectly when run seperately; however running them using the import function does not populate the "Dice_rolls.txt" file before varience.py is run. I have tried implementing a time.sleep() function, but the same error occurs.

**Solution**

Forgot to close the file after calling it in dice_rolls.py

Adding this in fixed the problem.

Comment: Your first file opens `Dice_rolls.txt` for writing, and never closes it.  Then you open it for reading.  That might be causing a problem.  You should always close files when you're done reading or writing them - don't just leave them open like that. especially when writing to them.  Use `Dicerolls.close()` to close it (as you do in the second file).

Comment: Oh my; that solved it!

Thank you! Can't believe I missed that